# поменять курсор на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как заменить курсор на сайте,на свой в формате .cur

Answer (score 2):

```
cursor: url(hyper.cur), auto;
```

url позволяет установить свой собственный курсор, для этого нужно указать путь к файлу с курсором.